# How can I contribute artwork to kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, icons, kde, contributing

I recently installed kubuntu on my PC.
I would like to change the icon of the system task bar and submit the icon so that it can replace the default icon in the kubuntu KDE 5 breeze theme.

Please help me how can I contribute my icon as I can't find   any info in the development page of kubuntu.
Its full of things for software dev.

Answer (score 1):

**Sharing**

If you want to share your artwork: http://kde-look.org

**Kubuntu**

Note ! The Kubuntu artwork is coming from the KDE. If you want to contact the Kubuntu developers:

Ubuntu irc channels: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IRC/ChannelList
- there is a Kubuntu devel channel.

Kubuntu devel mailing list: https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/kubuntu-devel

**KDE**

The KDE has own forums: https://forum.kde.org

There is sub forum - Visual Design Group: https://forum.kde.org/viewforum.php?f=285